# Unable to install Blog module in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I am new in drupal,as i worked on drupal 8 and trying install blog module but it it provided some following error:

```
Error message Unable to install Blog,

field.field.node.blog_post.field_blog_tags,

field.storage.node.field_blog_tags have unmet dependencies.
```

Any one can idea this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependencies of entity_reference module from the following two files

Folder:
blog/config/install

Files:
field.field.node.blog_post.field_blog_tags.yml
field.storage.node.field_blog_tags.yml

The functionality of entity_reference module is now part of Drupal 8.